# What backup utilities are available for Trixbox CE?

Tags: backup, trixbox

I'm running Trixbox CE (v2.6.2.3) and I need to make a full system backup of all configurations, recordings, databases, etc in a manner that can be easily restored on a brand new installation of the same version of Trixbox CE.

I started to write something myself using rsync, however I feel like I'm probably missing some things and needlessly copying other things.

What are my options? The back up module that normally works with FreePBX is not working with the stable version of Trixbox CE.

Answer (score 1):

I found this from tribox forum on a google search 
http://www.trixbox.org/forums/trixbox-forums/trixbox-projects/backup-and-restore

Comment: Unfortunately, the back up module does not play nicely with the current stable version of Trixbox.

Comment: Maybe you can improve the backup module further with whatever you were trying to do using rsync :) just a suggestion...

Comment: Yes, I'm just going to break down and write my own .. I'll update my question when I release it, maybe someone else will find it useful.

Comment: @Tim, great to hear that! :)

Answer (score 0):

I use Acronis True Image to clone the system. May lose some incremental settings, but we log those and all voicemail is sent to email. Not perfect, but better than nothing!